# LNK1107: invalid or corrupt file - what file is corrupt?

Tags: winapi, dll, command-line, windows-phone

I'm working on a Windows Phone 8 port of the Crypto++ library. I'm trying to create a DLL. I've been suffering a `LNK1107: invalid or corrupt file` error for far too long.

I've reduced the DLL build to a single object file called `dll-wp8.obj` with `DllMain`. When I try to link it, I get:

```
        "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\WPSDK\WP80\bin\x
86_arm\cl.exe" /nologo /D NDEBUG /W3 /Os /Oy- /D WINAPI_FAMILY=WINAPI_FAMILY_PHO
NE_APP  /AI "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Phone Kits\8.0\Windows Metadata" /FI
 SDKDDKVer.h /FI winapifamily.h  /WX- /GL /D _USRDLL /D _WINDLL /Gm- /EHsc /MD /
GS /fp:precise  /D CRYPTOPP_EXPORTS /D CRYPTOPP_DISABLE_ASM /D CRYPTOPP_DISABLE_
SSE2  /D CRYPTOPP_DISABLE_SSE3 -c dll-wp8.cpp
dll-wp8.cpp
        "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\WPSDK\WP80\bin\x
86_arm\link.exe" /nologo /release /manifest:no /subsystem:console /LTCG /TLBID:1
 /WINMD:NO  /DYNAMICBASE /NXCOMPAT /MACHINE:ARM /DLL /verbose WindowsPhoneCore.l
ib RuntimeObject.lib PhoneAppModelHost.lib /implib:cryptlib.lib /out:cryptlib.dl
l dll-wp8.obj

Starting pass 1
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\WPSDK\WP80\bin\x86_arm\li
nk.exe : fatal error LNK1107: invalid or corrupt file: cannot read at 0x2B8
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0
\VC\WPSDK\WP80\bin\x86_arm\link.exe"' : return code '0x453'
Stop.
```

The command line is consistent with what is created by a Visual Studio 2012/Windows Phone project. A similar empty project links fine under Visual Studio. **EDIT**: Visual Studio uses response files rather than driving the compiler directly. This may be related: [Capture Visual Studio response file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23451431/capture-visual-studio-response-file).

All the files appear to be found, and they are all ARM. The files are `WindowsPhoneCore.lib` `RuntimeObject.lib` `PhoneAppModelHost.lib` and `dll-wp8.obj`:

[image]

```
C:\Users\Jeffrey\cryptopp>dumpbin /headers dll-wp8.obj | findstr machine
             1C4 machine (ARM)
```

Removing the `/GL` from the compile switch and dumping symbols shows `DllMain` is exported:

```
C:\Users\Jeffrey\cryptopp>dumpbin /symbols dll-wp8.obj | findstr DllMain
2A4 00000000 SECTE1 notype ()    External     | DllMain
2A5 00000000 SECTE1 notype       Label        | $LN5@DllMain
2A8 00000000 SECTE2 notype       Static       | $pdata1$DllMain
2AD 00000000 SECTE3 notype       Static       | $unwind2$DllMain
```

How does one determine what file is invalid or corrupt?

Comment: You say you checked all the files, but you don't mention checking `cryptlib.lib`, and it doesn't appear in your screenshot.  Is it an ARM build?

Comment: Yes, its an ARM build. `cryptlib.dll` is the DLL, and `cryptlib.lib` is the import lib. They are what I am trying to build. I did try building *without* `/implib:cryptlib.lib`, but I got the same result. The [Liner Options](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y0zzbyt4.aspx) state the default import library name is used if omitted.

Comment: Sorry, of course it is.  Thinking of the open source cryptlib project I had a brain fart.

Comment: @arx - no problem. I experiment with Gutmaann's `cryptlib` too on occasion. Its a very well written library.